# Why php code written below require is not executing?

Tags: php

I have a php script where If I write some code above the require statement it works, but If I write below the require statement nothing happens, no errors, warnings nothing.

here is my code:

```
require ("../../include/session.php");
require ("include/--.php");
require ("include/--.php");
require ("include/--.php");
```

Everything I write above this require statements it works but anything below these don't.

Could anyone please tell my why this is happening.

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Place the code `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your script (above those four lines), run the code, and see if you get any errors.

Comment: And also, are the hyphens (`-`) file names or have you just removed the names for the purposes of this post?

Comment: @Mattios550 (-) are not filenames. this are used just in this post.
I also added error_reporting(E_ALL); but nothing happens :(

Comment: After the error reporting set: ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Okay. Are you sure that the files you are trying to include don't include anything else? I.E. it is not looping infinitely?

Comment: @ehp Comment each `require` statement one by one and check which file is causing the problem. Try this debugging.

Comment: do you have an exit statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have error reporting on. There is probably an error in some of your required files, and default behaviour for an PHP-conf is to die silently (at least with the preconfigured installation in the Ubuntu packages). There could also be an error with your file names.

Add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the top of your main PHP-file (the one that has the requires).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `require` files,maybe there is infinity loop in `require` files.

Comment: also see CPU usage if you are running Wamp or Zamp server.